# how solve Apache2 ssl Cert Problem with laravel

Tags: laravel, apache2, lets-encrypt

I have generated SSL Cert Using Letsencrypr and I  installed it in apache using this configuration in default-SSL.conf file under the sites-enabled  folder

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin info@qsinav.com
            ServerName demo.qsinav.com

            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/qSinav-starter/public

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.qsinav.com/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.qsinav.com/privkey.pem
            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>

            SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1.3
           #SSLHonorCipherOrder     off
           #SSLSessionTickets       off

             <Directory  /var/www/html/qSinav-starter/>
                AllowOverride all
             SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>


          </VirtualHost>
         </IfModule>
```

this configuration is working only with the login page of my system, and then when I doing login  it shows me

> not secure

I am not sure where the error should be.
thanks in advance

Comment: certbot can change your config for you, I would recommend to use that feature

Comment: check js console/instpector and you will see why not secure. usually you have assets(js,css,img) that not secure(http)

Comment: Check your .env file. Make sure `APP_SSL` is true

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution , there was in other pages  link that calling HTTP URL , after I removed it , it is working now